# List hidden service managed by an HSDIR

Tags: onion-services, relays, hsdir

if i have a relay with the HSdir flag, there is a way to know what are the hidden services descriptor hosted on it? 
in other word, can i list all hidden services present in the hash table of a relay?
or better how can i know what hidden services are managed by my relay?

thank you in advance for your reply.

**EDIT**

I would like list HS without modify tor's source code

Comment: Can you tell us your relays fingerprint?

Comment: i prefer not, but how my fingerprint can help ?

Comment: It might help with the process of advising you on this.

Comment: for istance we can assume that my fp is: ED6FA5CED61E9D8D05A6CC255FCBF1D430E8A901

Answer (score 2):

According to this post on the Tor blog: https://blog.torproject.org/category/tags/hidden-services

"If you don't know a hidden service address, then under the new system, you won't find it out just by hosting its HSDir entry."

The whole point of an onion service is that it can stay hidden if the owner wants to do so.

Comment: yes it is true, but at some point (every day) an hidden services to works need to pubblish its descriptor, so in my relay, if it is in the right fingerprint range, it store the HS's descriptor, now the question is: there is a better/faster/easier way to obtain it? or the only way is modify TOR's source code?

Comment: The system is designed so you can't obtain it. I guess if you can modify the source code, you could extract the descriptors, but there might be safeguards, otherwise the FBI, NSA, and CIA would have already done it.

Comment: yes, if i will modify the source code is possible to obtain the both descriptor and  HS onion address, on doing this for the descriptor, i'm pretty sure that there is no security issue for the system, indeed descriptors che be also retrieved  without modify the source code, like using HSFETCH with tor controll port. My point is to list onion hidden services managed by my own relay, preferably without modify tor source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the descriptors published on your HSDir, but Tor strongly requests you not do that.

Here's a writeup on the topic.

http://donncha.is/2013/05/trawling-tor-hidden-services/

Comment: thank you for the reply, if i remember well the author of this article have modified tor's source code.

Comment: The basic technique still works.  But it's officially naughty and making it no longer work is on Tor's roadmap.